# Can login into docker-registry but not push image (github)

Tags: docker, github, docker-registry, github-package-registry

So I want to use the docker registry from GitHub.
I do the flowing:

```
docker login docker.pkg.github.com --username username
docker build . --tag docker.pkg.github.com/user-name/repo/IMAGENAME:snapshot
docker push docker.pkg.github.com/user-name/repo/IMAGENAME:snapshot
```

Note that the repository is private and not mine but I got write access to it.

When I go to packages tab I can also see the instructions on how to get started and I follow them(kind of, I tag the docker image in one go).

But when I run the 3 commands at the top I get the following output(push command fails):

```
unauthorized: Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:packages'], but your token has only been granted the: [''] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: https://github.com/settings/tokens.
```

When I visit the site referenced there is nothing there only unrelated tokens.

Any ideas what I could try or what may cause this...?

Comment: Well in the docs it say use a token https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages but then why do they suggest login via docker login --username username on their page. Also when typing in the pw on the command line it says I am now logged in.

Comment: Works with self issues token, I am still not happy. Why does it not work when I login via password and why is it suggested if it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an API Token to log in like shown in the docs. Log in via password is not possible.
https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-docker-for-use-with-github-packages

> You must use a personal access token.